# Find the total number of 20 digit codes that can be formed using the numbers {0,1,2,3,4}, such that consecutive digits have a difference of 1?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

To start with an example of such a code can be: 
$34321210123212343210$

I have no clue how this property can be mathematically counted. I actually even have a short solution of this question which I could not make any sense of. I will type the solution at the bottom of this body, one may choose to solve it themselves first and then refer the solution.

I could notice some obvious properties that if there occurs the digit $4,$ it must have $3$ on both sides. And similarly the digit $0$ must have $1$ on both sides.

I am not able to think any way to solve this problem. Please help me with an explanatory solution. Thank you in advance.

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

...............................................................................................................................................

SOLUTION:
Let $A_n$ denote number of codes which end in $0$ or $4,$ $B_n$ denote number of codes which end in $1$ or $3$ and $C_n$ denote number of codes which ends with $2.$ 
$A_{n+1} = B_n = C_{n+1}, B_{n+1} = A_n + 2C_n$ 
Thus $N= 2^3\cdot 3^9$

Comment: An interesting question, but I don't agree with your solution

Comment: The recurrence looks correct to me, $A_{n+1}$ is the number of length $n+1$ strings that start with $0$ or $4$ so the next digit must be $1$ or $3$.

Comment: I agree that $A(n+1)=C(n+1)=B(n)$  and $B(n+1) = A(n) + 2C(n)$.  Interestingly, I think we can conclude that $B(n+1)= 3 B(n-1)$.

Comment: @Ninad   Do you understand why $A(n+1)= B(n)$?

Comment: Indeed $B(n+1) = 3B(n-1)$ because for this class the last 3 digits must be: 101, 121, 123, 341, 323, 321.  Since $B(1) = 2, B(2) = 4$ by exhaustive listing, this solves all $B$, and from that, also solves all $A$ and $C$.  nice!!

Comment: @saulspatz The answer is apparently correct for $n=20$ (the value of $n$ indicated in the question title)

Comment: See [OEIS sequence A090993](https://oeis.org/A090993).

Comment: @RobertIsrael neat, how did you find that?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I think I've been having a lot of senior moments today.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Compute the first few terms and search.

Comment: @RobertIsrael makes sense, thanks for the tip

Comment: I got it now. I thank everyone for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to frame the problem using linear algebra:

Let $A_{i,n}$ denote the number of valid codes that start with $i$ (which can be $0,1,2,3,$ or $4$) and have length $n$.  We note that a valid code that begins with a $0$ of length $n$ must be a $0$ followed by a valid code that begins with $1$ of length $n-1$.  Similarly, a valid code that begins with $1$ of length $n$ must be a $1$ followed by a valid code that begins with $2$, or a $1$ followed by a valid code that begins with a $0$.

Putting all these observations together, we find that the $A_{i,n}$ satisfy the following system of recurrences:
$$
A_{0,n} = A_{1,n-1}\\
A_{1,n} = A_{0,n-1} + A_{2,n-1}\\
A_{2,n} = A_{1,n-1} + A_{3,n-1}\\
A_{3,n} = A_{2,n-1} + A_{4,n-1}\\
A_{4,n} = A_{3,n-1}
$$
for any integer $n > 1$.  That is: for integers $n>1$, we have
$$
\pmatrix{A_{0,n}\\A_{1,n}\\A_{2,n}\\A_{3,n}\\A_{4,n}}= 
\pmatrix{0&1&0&0&0\\
1&0&1&0&0\\
0&1&0&1&0\\
0&0&1&0&1\\
0&0&0&1&0}
\pmatrix{A_{0,n-1}\\A_{1,n-1}\\A_{2,n-1}\\A_{3,n-1}\\A_{4,n-1}}
$$
With $A_{i,1} = 1$ for all $i$. With this recursive characterization, we see that we can calculate the desired quantity as
$$
A_{0,n} + \cdots + A_{4,n} = \pmatrix{1&\cdots&1}\pmatrix{A_{0,n}\\A_{1,n}\\A_{2,n}\\A_{3,n}\\A_{4,n}}\\
= \pmatrix{1&1&1&1&1}
\pmatrix{0&1&0&0&0\\
1&0&1&0&0\\
0&1&0&1&0\\
0&0&1&0&1\\
0&0&0&1&0}^{n-1}
\pmatrix{1\\1\\1\\1\\1}
$$

---

This leads us to the following answer: let $M$ denote the matrix
$$
M = \pmatrix{0&1&0&0&0\\
1&0&1&0&0\\
0&1&0&1&0\\
0&0&1&0&1\\
0&0&0&1&0}
$$
We note that $M$ is [symmetric, tridiagonal and Toeplitz (German wiki link)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal-Toeplitz-Matrix).  Thus, we find that its eigenvalues and eigenvectors have the form
$$
\lambda_k = -2 \cos \left( \frac{\pi k}{6}\right), \quad k = 1,\dots,5\\
v^{(k)} = \pmatrix{\sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{6}\right) & \cdots & \sin\left(\frac{5\pi k}{6}\right)}^T, \quad  k = 1,\dots,5
$$
Let $Q$ denote the matrix $Q = \pmatrix{v^{(1)} & \cdots & v^{(5)}}$, and let $y$ denote the vector $y = \pmatrix{1&1&1&1&1}^T$.  Let $x = \pmatrix{x_1 & \cdots & x_5}^T$ denote the solution to the equation $Qx = y$.  Once we compute the solution $x$ to the above equation, we can answer our original question with the formula
$$
N_{n} = y^TM^{n-1}y = \sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2 \lambda_k^{n-1} = \\
-2^{n-1} x_1^2 \cos^{n-1}\left( \frac{\pi}{6}\right) 
-2^{n-1} x_2^2 \cos^{n-1}\left( \frac{2\pi}{6}\right) - \cdots 
-2^{n-1} x_5^2 \cos^{n-1}\left( \frac{5\pi}{6}\right)
$$
It is useful to note in the above that $\cos(3 \pi /6) = 0$.

It is notable that, because $M$ has characteristic polynomial $p(x) = x^5 - 4x^3 + 3x$, the sequence $N_n$ itself satisfies the linear recurrence
$$
N_n = 4N_{n-2} - 3N_{n-4}, \qquad n \geq 6
$$

[Computation with W|A](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1,1,1,1,1%7D%7D%20*%20%7B%7B0,1,0,0,0%7D,%7B1,0,1,0,0%7D,%7B0,1,0,1,0%7D,%7B0,0,1,0,1%7D,%7B0,0,0,1,0%7D%7D%5E19%20*%20%7B%7B1%7D,%7B1%7D,%7B1%7D,%7B1%7D,%7B1%7D%7D) indicates that our solution is $N_{20} = 157464$, which can indeed be factored as $N_{20} = 2^3 \cdot 3^9$.

---

Another approach: starting with the original recurrences and substituting the equations into themselves yields
$$
A_{0,n} = A_{0,n-2} + A_{2,n-2}\\
A_{1,n} = 2A_{1,n-2} + A_{3,n-2}\\
A_{2,n} = A_{0,n-2} + 2A_{2,n-2} + A_{4,n-2}\\
A_{3,n} = A_{1,n-2} + 2A_{3,n-2}\\
A_{4,n} = A_{2,n-2} + A_{4,n-2}
$$
If you prefer matrix calculation, this amount to the observation that
$$
\mathbf{A}_n = M^2 \mathbf A_{n-2}
$$

However, with the symmetry of the problem we observe that $A_{1,n} = A_{3,n}$ and $A_{0,n} = A_{4,n}$, which means that we can simplify the above system to
$$
A_{0,n} = A_{0,n-2} + A_{2,n-2}\\
A_{1,n} = 3A_{1,n-2}\\
A_{2,n} = 2A_{0,n-2} + 2A_{2,n-2}\\
$$
It follows that 
$$
N_{2n} = 2A_{0,n} + 2A_{1,n} + A_{2,n}\\
= 2(A_{0,n-2} + A_{2,n-2}) + 2(3A_{1,n-2}) + (2A_{0,n-2} + 2A_{2,n-2})\\
= 3(2A_{0,n-2} + 2A_{2,n-2} + A_{2,n-2}) = 3 N_{n-2}
$$
Calculating $N_2 = 8$ leads us to the conclusion that
$$
N_{2n} = 8 \cdot 3^{n-1}
$$
which allows us to easily calculate $N_{20}$.

Answer (score 1):

another approach is using the zigzag counts on board

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|}
                       & 0                      & 1                      & 2                       & 3                      & 4                    \\ \hline 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1  \\ \hline 
2 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1  \\ \hline 
3 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 3 & 2  \\ \hline 
4 & 3 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 3  \\ \hline 
5 & 6 & 9 & 12 & 9 & 6  \\ \hline
\end{array}

here it's a 5x5 board, let the vertical axis show the steps from top to bottom and vertical axis denote the digits $\{0..4\}$.  The cells are the number of zigzag patterns to that cell (sum of two upper diagonal neighbors).  Horizontal sum will give the count, for example for $N_1=5, N_2=8, N_3=14, etc.$  It's clear that there is an odd/even difference.  You can formulate the total count for any n as

$$
N_n = 2 \cdot (4+3 ( n \bmod 2 )) \cdot 3^{\lfloor \frac{n-2}2 \rfloor} ,\;\; n > 1
$$

Here $(n \bmod 2)$ is used to indicate odd parity.

Comment: The zigzag count seems like a nice characterization, but how did you arrive at that formula for $N_n$?  Also, why is it "clear" that there's an odd/even difference?

Comment: starting with the base n=2 and n=3, each consecutive row is just triple of the same parity one.  The rest is some creativity to put in one formula instead of two for odd/even.

Comment: I see.  So in other words, the even rows satisfy
$$
N_{2n} = 8 \cdot 3^{n-1}
$$
which nicely explains why the final answer factors so well

Comment: right., odd will have a $7$ factor.